# PostBack in ASP.NET causes all TextBox and DropList in GridView to be cleared

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view in asp.net as given below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid_flats_allflatslist" OnRowDeleting="grid_flats_allflatslist_RowDeleting" runat="server" Width="95%" CssClass="gridview" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" BackColor="Black" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" frame="below" DataKeyNames="BlockID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlockID" HeaderText="Block ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlockName" HeaderText="Block Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flat Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_flats_listflatnumber" CssClass="textbox" onkeypress="return numeric(this);" MaxLength="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Flat Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="list_flats_listflattype" CssClass="droplist" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Bachelor" Value="Bachelor"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Family" Value="Family"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Max Vacancy">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="text_flats_listmaxvacancy" onkeypress="return numeric(this);" MaxLength="2" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Delete" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#9e4900" ForeColor="#fff1e5" Font-Bold="false" Font-Underline="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#9e4900" ForeColor="#fff1e5" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#ff8080" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffe7d6" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffd6ba" ForeColor="#660000" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#fff9f4" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="button_flats_flatplus" CssClass="button" Height="30px" Width="25%" runat="server" Text="Add Flat" OnClick="button_flats_flatplus_Click" />
```

Initially, this is empty and when I click on the `button_flats_flatsplus` button then a row will be added to the grid view with the field as above. It will also have 2 text boxes and a drop-down list. The button click event is as below.

```
protected void button_flats_flatplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr = null;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] == null)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BlockID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BlockName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["BlockID"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedValue; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["BlockName"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedItem.Text; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable) ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["BlockID"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedValue; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["BlockName"] = list_flats_blocklist.SelectedItem.Text; // I get this value from a different list
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
        grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
    }
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

After I add many rows the grid view will look as below,

[image: My GridView]

If I press delete then that particular row it is getting deleted successfully but the values in all the other rows are cleared. My row deleting code is as below with the `SetPreviousData` function but it won't work.

```
protected void grid_flats_allflatslist_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    DataTable dt = ViewState["CurrentTable"] as DataTable;
    dt.Rows[index].Delete();
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    grid_flats_allflatslist.DataSource = dt;
    grid_flats_allflatslist.DataBind();
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

Everytime I add a new row to the grid view or delete a row from the grid view, post back happens and whatever values I have entered into the text boxes and drop-down list of other rows gets cleared. I tried to handle this with `!Page.IsPostBack` but still not working.

Then I tried the following code and added it to all the places that had a postback or data bind to the grid view.

```
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)grid_flats_allflatslist.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("text_flats_listflatnumber");
                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)grid_flats_allflatslist.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("list_flats_listflattype");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)grid_flats_allflatslist.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("text_flats_listmaxvacancy");
                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                box2.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to add `!Page.IsPostBack` in the grid vide bind then whatever changes I make to grid view, add or delete rows is not getting reflected. How can I avoid clearing of the text boxes in grid view whenever there is a post back or data bind on the page? I still want to delete and add rows to grid view by still keeping the already entered values in the fields.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code ?? is there any rows exist in the `ViewState` list ?

Comment: Yes the rows are working fine, only the values entered in the textboxes gets cleared

Answer (score 0):

**I have tested your code, and it works just fine.**

You may not defined the `ViewState["CurrentTable"]` properly. **This is what i added to your code:**

```
 public DataTable CurrentTable
        {
            get
            {
                return (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = value;
            }
        }
```

*A `GIF` to describe how it works.

[image]

**EDIT**
I would suggest the following in order to be able to keep the data on the gridview :

`ViewState` List should have the values:

```
public class CustomDataTable
{
    public int BlockID { get; set; }
    public string BlockName { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

And its property :

```
public List<CustomDataTable> CurrentTable
{
    get
    {
        return (List<CustomDataTable>)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = value;
    }
}
```

**In the Picture below;**

- What `Add Flat` button should do is to populate a new default row into the gridview.
- Whenever `Save` button clicked , it should **store** that row data into
  the **CurrentTable**.
- Whenever `Delete` button clicked , it should **Remove** that row from
  the **CurrentTable**.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for `low-quality` GIF, but i think it will do :)

Comment: But this is the same as i have done..its working for me also. Read my question carefully. If i enter any values in existing record and then delete or add a new record, all entered values gets cleared

Comment: But, the values that **CurrentTable** hold are the default values(The assigned values on creation row). Actually using the `ViewState` in this case is useless. @ManoPrathibhanC